# Is this method of taking part of a string in a 64-bit system legal?

Tags: c, 64-bit, substring, 32bit-64bit, strncpy

This code evaluates a response from a web server. Here, we will assume the response is only two lines. One line showing the webpage status and one showing another random HTTP entry and no HTML code. In my code, buf (aka buffer) will contain this data. I then use strchr to find the line break but it returns a pointer.

I then take the buffer pointer and the pointer to the matching string data and subtract the two and get the absolute result. The reason I want an absolute result is because I need a positive number in order for the first portion of the buffer to be copied to the new buffer correctly.

Is this method of subtracting two char pointers and obtaining a result as an absolute value legal for a 64-bit system or will I have to make additional calculations? The reason I ask is because on a 64-bit system, the sizes of some data elements are different and I think if I don't be careful, I could cause a segmentation fault in either strncpy or even in the calculation of the 3rd parameter in strncpy.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char buf[500] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nsomething: something";
    char* p = strchr(buf, '\n');
    if (p) {
        char news[500];
        memset(news, 0, 500);
        strncpy(news, buf, abs(p - buf));
        printf("%s\n", news);
    } else {
        printf("Can't read line!\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `strcpy()` `strncpy()` is more evil than safe, for instance it could skip the terminating `nul`. And don't use `abs()` `p` cannot become larger than `buf` for that, instead use a `ptrdiff_t` variable.

Comment: `abs()` is not declared in either `<stdio.h>` or `<string.h>` — it's in `<stdlib.h>`.  Other than that, it looks OK.  I'd prefer to avoid the `memset()` and do an explicit 'set the null terminator byte'.  I'd also prefer to see you check that the length is small enough to fit in `news`.

Comment: @iharob: It can't use `strcpy()`; it needs to copy a subset of the string that is not null-terminated.  `memcpy()` perhaps...

Comment: Jonathan, I doubt the first line of an HTTP response code which is what I'm interested in is more than 500 bytes. Heck, I could really go down to maybe 20ish bytes because its the status number thats important. and why avoid memset? I'm just trying to prepare the allocated memory so all data bytes in it are null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing (substracting pointers) is perfectly legal. The only problem is that with strncpy, your copied string will not be null-terminated. The usual use of strncpy is to avoid buffer overflow, but you are on a particular case where you want to copy a part of the string. You will need to add the null termination:

```
strncpy(news, buf, p - buf);
*(news + (p - buf)) = '\0';
```

Comment: There is no need to add null-termination since the whole `news` buffer was filled with nulls on the previous line. (Unless `p-buf`≥ 500, in which case both approaches are broken.)